# Attribute [Bind(Exclude="")] fails to prevent over-posting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

What is the best way to prevent MVC 4 over-posting?

According to MS sources, the [Bind] attribute is supposed to be the easiest way to prevent over-posting by preventing incoming form values from making it to the database.  With the latest version of MVC & EF this does not seem to be working as expected/advertised, unless I'm missing something major.

From *Wrox Professional ASP.NET MVC 4* (Jon Galloway's Chapter 7), the following class should prevent over-posting:

```
[Bind(Exclude="IsAdmin")]
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

But all the [Bind] attribute does is prevent the form submission values from binding to the model.  The model then has a blank/default value, which is written back to the database.  In this case, it would ensure that IsAdmin = false EVERY TIME you call .SaveChanges() using this model.  Any "true" values are overwritten.  That's a HUGE security failure.

The alternate syntax - placing [Bind] in the Edit controller action parameter - does the exact same thing:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "IsAdmin")] User user)
```

All "true" values are overwritten when .SaveChanges() is called, contradicting K. Scott Allen's blog post on the topic: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

The only alternative seems to be a flurry of dedicated ViewModels all wired up with Automapper.  While secure, that seems like a MASSIVE headache, especially as:

- You may have different requirements for Create, Edit, Index, and Detail actions, requiring different ViewModels
- You may need to expose some read-only fields (such as CreatedBy on the Edit action) that cannot have the [ReadOnly] attribute on the property because they are updated by the Create action

I know that somebody is going to respond by saying you should **never** bind data models to views, but that is the default template behavior and the way it's shown in nearly all documentation.  And besides, MVC + EF was supposed to make life *easier*, not *harder*, and an ocean of ModelView classes wired up with AutoMapper is not what I consider easier.

So does anybody know how to make [Bind] function as advertised?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may have mislead by the Wrox book on this occasion. What you describe is the intended behaviour of the Bind/Exclude property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.exclude(v=vs.108).aspx.

If you do not want to bind values to every property on your model, I believe that ViewModels are they way to go, even though as you rightly point out they are something of an overhead. Nevertheless, the advantages of using them are significant, and IMO in this sort of context, justify the extra development work. For example:

- Allowing partial entity updates
- presenting data from multiple entities
- decoupling the UI from the domain model, allowing you to vary labels, validation rules, error messages

Automapper is one option for doing the mapping from the entity to view models, but if you are using Lazy Loading, beware. I discovered Automapper doesn't handle updates to EF Proxy classes in the way I hoped. In the end I removed AM and rolled my own mapping mechanism based on an IMappable interface and a generic utility class. In many cases it's not much more code to type to do that than to configure Automapper.

Comment: Thanks, good advice, but several questions/comments:
1) You still have the null over-posting problem when you migrate your data to the entity model.  Even though that data wasn't in the view model, that property is in the data model, and if EF always sends all fields, you'll overwrite existing data.
2) Galloway and Allen are two of the biggest names in MVC documentation, and they're both very clear that [Bind] is the easiest solution.  Are they both totally wrong, or did something change?

Comment: On further thought, I'm beginning to think that the problem is with the `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;` syntax used to tell EF that a record has changed.  This sets state on the whole record, including unbound properties, introducing a serious problem.  If instead EF only set .IsModified on *bound* fields (honoring [Bind]) things would work.  Does anybody know if this is new behavior in EF 5?

Comment: @Neil Laslett For an insert, any data not in your view model will get default  values or will need to be given values by your controller before saving. For updates, the technique I use is to retrieve the record I want to update, then apply new values from the view model. Use a timestamp field in your viewmodel if you are concerned about concurrency.

Comment: @Neil Laslett. AFAIK, nothing has changed in Bind functionality. If you think about it, if your model contains fields that do not get values from the form on binding, .NET has to give them a value (the default for the datatype) when it instantiates the object in the binder. If you make those fields nullable types, they will be null after binding if they do not receive a value. You could detect such fields and not apply the update in your save processing if you want.

Comment: I was hoping that EF would be smarter about generating the SQL UPDATE and honor [Bind], even though the properties exist in the model. Given your advice, it seems the default Edit actions are unusable given any complexity in the model. Your approach of retrieving existing values and then binding against that (so EF really does know what has been modified) seems like the best way to go.

Comment: I'm going to leave this question open for another day or two, just to see if anybody has anything else to add about [Bind] specifically.  Here's another semi-official post claiming that [Bind] solves over-posting: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: @NeilLaslett, that article refers to the use of the Exclude attribute to prevent a malicious user tampering with a form to update fields on the record other than the intended ones. That, as I understand it, is the purpose of the Exclude attribute. To prevent unauthorised data passing into the action method, rather than as a directive to EF during data updates.

Comment: Accepting on your general point that [Bind] does not do what the many print and on-line authors say it does: prevent HTTP over-posts.  It also does not _really_ do what you say (prevent users from tampering with unintended fields) because EF will ALWAYS "tamper" with those fields anyway.  You may ignore user-generated content but you still get null/empty values pushed into your database, which is not much better. This is the intended behavior.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx, note at end. Also see my alternate solution at http://bit.ly/WSTpHW

Answer (score 0):

If you revert back to manuel model binding, you should not have any problems. If you do not place an input for "IsAdmin" your model will retain its original value. This adds a few lines of extra code but saves a lot of time by not generating not maintaining ViewModels.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(id);
    if (user != null)
        TryUpdateModel(user);
    else
        return HttpNotFound();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```