# MVC4 Post form null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a grid when the client click on Edit for one like a form is open. the User can Edit only some values (let the user to edit only the Shipping date for the current order) but when I send the Form the values of the non editable field are NULL on Post

When I display :

```
@Html.Display(model => model.Rep)
```

or :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

the Values are displayed correctly but when I submit the form the Value are Null.
the View :

```
@model Models.Orders
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="~/Content/pure-release-0.5.0/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <body>
    <form class="pure-form">
        <fieldset>
             <legend>A Stacked Form</legend>
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" aria-disabled="true" aria-readonly="true">
                    <label for="first-name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rep)</label>
                    @Html.Display(model => model.Rep)
                </div>
                <div class="pure-g">
                    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" aria-readonly="true">
                        <label for="first-name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </body>
}
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Titre").click(function () {
            $(this).next('.Contenu').slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $("#Model").prop('disabled', true);
    });
</script>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}^
```

The model :

```
 public class Orders
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Rep { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

When the User click on Edit on the Grid:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Orders order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

On post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Orders order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(order);
    }
```

When I debug I find theat the Values on order are NULL

I Thought that the problem was the waay that I sent data from my grid to the form but i change the easyui to Use GridMVC and still have the problem.

I used : in View TextBoxFor for readOnly + disabled as attribut but same problem

I tried :
in the Model : `[ReadOnly(true)]` 
+  in the View : `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rep)` but I was able to edit Rep That I want to block

I tried to make the EditorFor readonly with Javascript but I was able to edit

Can you help me please, I tried all what I found but there is something missing in my code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  Trying to short cut with the MVC CRUD template.  I like what @PaulTaylor suggested:

[Attribute [Bind(Exclude=“”)] fails to prevent over-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13539060/3175526)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Readonly values are not submitted to server (at least by modern browsers).

If you want to submit this value you can create a hidden field instead of a textbox:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientName)
```

This will effectively submit your value to server

Comment: Thanks `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientName)` will hide the field I want to show these field to the user only display it without let him edit these values

Comment: If you want to display readonly value and also submit it to the server, you can submit the hidden field for the value, and also output value using any HTML you want, e.g. <div>@Model.ClientName</div>. This way you get both submitted value and any html you want

Comment: Thanks dotnetom acctually I don't want to submit ClientName, it's only to update some values, Example let the user to edit only the Shipping date for the current order

Comment: In that case I suggest using any html you want and output the value using @Model.ClientName

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using 2 forms: one nested to the other. You have to remove the second and add the css class to the first. The `Html.BeginForm()` will create another form.
You can try something like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","controllerName",null,FormMethod.Post,{@class="pure-form"}))
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <body>
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)    
    <fieldset>
         <legend>A Stacked Form</legend>
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" aria-disabled="true" aria-readonly="true">
                <label for="first-name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rep)</label>
                @Html.Display(model => model.Rep)
            </div>
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" aria-readonly="true">
                    <label for="first-name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</body>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, the field are disabled but the values are null

Comment: I have updated with the `ID` field as Hidden. The values are null or the model is not valid? Because if you don't pass all fields the Binder will not able to build a Order correctly. Put a breakpoint to see if your values are null as you said. Just add the ID

Comment: Yes the ID field is hidden as you suggest, I break on Edit in the controller and the Model is valid `if (ModelState.IsValid)` return true

Comment: @ProtoCus if it is true, do you still pass null values?

Comment: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Orders order)` Order--> ClientName = null

Comment: Try to remove this line:`  <label for="first-name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)</lable>`. I am not sure but, you can also check the source code of your page in the browser to see if the name `ClientName ` of the input is correct?

Comment: What I have in the source code : `  <form action="/Orders/Edit/193" class="pure-form" method="post">
  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="193" />      
  <fieldset>

   <input disabled="disabled" id="ClientName" name="ClientName" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="12" /> `

Answer (score 0):

Your text box is disabled. The inputs with `disabled` attribute set do not get submitted with the form. You can verify this by using network tab of Chrome dev tool or your favorite browser. If you want the text boxes disabled, use just readonly and not the disabled. So, your text box should be as below:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, new {@readonly = "readonly" })
```

Afterwards, you can use jQuery and CSS to make them look like disabled by graying them out if you like but do not use disabled if you want the values to come through.

Comment: Thank you I tried what you suggest but on send on the form I have null for clientName this is the View source of the page before Sending `<form action="/Orders/Edit/202" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="202" /><fieldset>
             <div class="pure-g">
                <div aria-disabled="true" aria-readonly="true">
                    <div class="ClientName"><label for="ClientName">Sales</label>
The Client Name</div>`

Comment: Even if I put ( `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName)` without `new { @readonly = "readonly"}`the sent Value is null

Comment: It could be in html source but will not get submitted if it is disabled.Have you looked chrome's network tab? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index   What is `$("#Model").prop('disabled', true);` doing? Is there something named Model on the page? Try removing/commenting that line.

Comment: apparently both `disabled` and `readonly` attributes are doing the same thing. Both are graying the field and values in the both cases is `null`.